# Parsing Pages in word document using StringBuilder

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to parse a word file pages and to edit every page content : so i used the Apache Poi API to parse a word content and replace some texts in it , that works fine.
But this i couldn't find a way to parse the word document pages. There is a method returning a StringBuilder representing the document content, this method is declared in the `org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument`  .

`java.lang.StringBuilder   getText()    Internal method to access document texte`

So can i access pages from returning StringBuilder?

Comment: If the method is internal, you shouldn't be able to call it. StringBuilder, however, shouldn't be an issue, because it's essentially a mutable String.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight is there a way to find a page separator in StringBuilder object this is what i was thinking about?

Comment: If there is a way to find a page separator (whatever that char sequence is) in a `String`, there should be a way to find it in a `StringBuidler` as well.